# Printing a .txt on the screen

Tags: java, file, netbeans, filereader

I'm trying to print a .txt on the screen.I have a menu with different options and I don't know why it fails. The file directory should be defined by the string FITXER. I only want to print the text file, I don't need to save the content. The bug is on the `BufferedReader` and `FileReader arxiu`, it's the name of the file variable that gets the value of FITXER.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.io.*;

public class Copiador {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Copiador programa = new Copiador();
        programa.inici();
    }

    public void inici() throws IOException {
        int opcio;

        do {
            System.out.println("Llegir (1)");
            System.out.println("Copiar (2)");
            System.out.println("Surtir (3)");

            opcio = sc.nextInt();

            switch (opcio) {
                case 1:
                    Llegir();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Skipped Consultar");
                    //Consultar(nomusuaris);
                    break;
            }
        } while (opcio != 3);
        sc.close();
    }

    public void Llegir() throws IOException {

        String FITXER;
        File arxiu = null;
        FileReader fr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

        System.out.println("Que vols llegir?");
        FITXER = sc.nextLine();
        arxiu = new File(FITXER);
        fr = new FileReader(arxiu);

        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String linea;
        while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(linea);

        System.out.println("Confirmat");
        fr.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: You should try: `FITXER = sc.next();` to read the name of the archive file